# Why is the "H" in Hector pronounced?

Tags: pronunciación, ortografía, nombres-propios

The letter "H" is usually (always?) silent in Spanish. So why is the name "Hector" pronounced "Heck-ter" and not "Eck-ter"?

Or is "Hector" an anglicization of the spelling of a name which is really "Jector"?

Comment: I've never heard Hector pronounced with aspiration. There are a handful of dialects that preserve initial aspiration, but only with words that etymologically had an f- in those words (and I don't think Hector is such a thing)

Comment: I reckon the Hector I know is introduced that way for "us Gringos" then.

Comment: Is this when he introduces himself in Spanish or in English? I know I introduce myself with different names or pronunciations of them depending on the language I'm speaking, and that may be what he's doing.

Comment: Yes, he doesn't speak Spanish to me, so he probably Americanized the pronunciation of his name for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be a regional variation, but at least in Spain I always heard it like "Eck-tor" with the "H" being silent. I have actually heard some people pronouncing it as "ejj-tor".

Héctor comes from the Greek (one of the heroes of the Illiad), and means *Steadfast*.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about regional variations but at least I've never heard it like that, the H is always silent.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing this word pronunciation in english language with spanish where the *H* has no sound at all.  There is no possibility of pronouncing Hector in spanish the same way as english. Always H is silent.

Comment: There are a handful of dialects in Extremadura, Andalucía, Cantabria, and the Canary Islands that maintain H with aspiration (but generally only in etymologically *f-* words)

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the H should be silent.

I think there may be leeway in the pronunciation of the J sound like, "Juan" or "Ciudad Juarez".  I have heard with a strong H sound, and sometimes hardly at all.